# How to do priority based processing

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I have a linked list containing n processes and these processes are sorted in an decreasing order of priority to run. So , the 1st process i.e. 1st node of linked list has the maximum priority, then the 2nd node and so on.
At one time instance I can only run 8 processes. What I want to do is that I want 6 highest priority and 2 lowest priority to run at one time instant.

What I had done is that I rearranged the linked list where the first six nodes will be having highest priority and the next two nodes with lowest priority. Then further 6 nodes of high priority and 2 low priority and repeating this until all nodes are covered. But this does not do what I want i.e. if any of the 6 highest priority process ends then another high priority process should take it's place and if a low priority process ends then a low priority may take its place.

How can I implement this? (also this is my first question so if there are any problems in the way I had put my question please point it out)

Comment: Why not use a doubly linked list that you can iterate through forwards from the front and backwards from the back?

Comment: How dynamic is this list? Could it be that new nodes are inserted anywhere in the list while others are being processed? Can priorities change of nodes that are already in the list? Should processing be interrupted if a better candidate shows up, or will you always finish what you started? Do you need thread-safety, or is everything handled by a single thread?

Comment: list is already created and given to you as a singly linked list. And no more processes will be added after this list was initially created. There will be no priority changes further while processing.

Comment: @Ian Abbott i used doubly linked list and most of my requirements were met. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solve this problem with 2 methods.

1. Anyhow use this `list` as `deque`. `Deque` is nothing but a data
   structure like `queue` where we can push and pop elements from both top as well
   as bottom of `queue`.  Now we will maintain 2 counters, `High-counter`
   and `Low-counter`. `High-counter` will keep track of `6` High priority
   processes will Low-counter will keep track of `2` Low priority
   processes. So High-counter will have max value `6` while Low-counter
   will have `2`. At start, initialize both counters with zero.

   Now while `High-counter < 6` , pop top element from `dequeue` and
   increment the `High-counter`. Again while `Low-counter < 2` , pop bottom
   element from `dequeue` and increment the `Low-counter`. If any High
   priority process completes, we will decrement the `High-counter` and
   similar for low priority process. Now since, Counters are less than
   their respective maximum values, we will use a while loop and repeat
   previous two while loops until `Deque` is empty. Also note that here popping process means running them.
2. Use the similar approach but this time with semaphores in place of counters.

*I am not claiming, my solution is 100% correct but still it's close to the answer.* Also tag the question with operating system so as to attract better answers.

Comment: I used a doubly linked list and it worked. My whole code is based on a linked list type structure and I cannot change that for now. But using deque is also good option. Thank you!

Comment: The above algo too needs doubly linked list. Because we also need to access elements from other side.